# How can I convert the 400 to percentage? "scrollY": 400,

Tags: javascript, percentage

I am working on a div scroller and found this javascript. I would like to convert it so I can use percentage.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollY":        400, /*This changes the height of the DIV Scroller*/
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "jQueryUI":       true
    } );
} );

    </script>
```

"Scrolly": 400,  would like to turn it into %

Comment: Percentage of what exactly? To get a percentage you would have to calculate 400 against some other value.

Comment: divide by 4 may help you.

Answer (score 0):

try something for calculate percentage

```
var sc = $(window).scrollTop(),
        dh = $(document).height(),
        ch = $(window).height();
        scrollPercent = (sc / (dh-ch)) * 100;
```

Comment: instead of using pixsels I want to user percentage.